# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when routing AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment to custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My ELB instance works fine on the dedicated elasticbeanstalk.com subdomain, however when I route it to my custom domain https://hoodie.dev, it returns ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Before adding an HTTPS rule to my inbound rules, it returned ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

I have already tried changing the security groups, currently I am allowing:

- HTTPS from 0.0.0.0
- HTTP from 0.0.0.0
- SSH from 0.0.0.0

I'm relatively new to using AWS and web development, so I would appreciate if your answers are detailed.

Comment: It sounds like you are testing both a custom domain, and adding SSL at the same time here, and it's not clear which one of those two things isn't working. It looks like `http://hoodie.dev` works, but it is setup to redirect to `https://hoodie.dev` which doesn't work. Please edit your question to add more details: Are you using a load balancer or single instance environment? What are the **specific** details of the HTTPS configuration.

Comment: Apologies. I am not sure how I would use a load balancer, as I stated I am quite new to web development as a whole. I selected the security group generated for the environment, so I am assuming I am using a single instance environment.

Comment: Please specify how are you routing the domains, using Route53?

Comment: Elastic beanstalk will create a load balanced environment, or a single instance environment. Which one of those did you pick? If you picked a single instance environment, you have to obtain the SSL certificate and configure the web server running on Elastic Beanstalk to serve that certificate. Did you do any of that?

Comment: I am using Route53 to route my environment to the domain. I never obtained an SSL certificate.

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Should I make it a load balanced environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured this out thanks to the help of @Mark B

I had to configure my elastic beanstalk instance and changed it from single environment to load balanced.
A video that helped me with this this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBOcPxho_wg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).